# "symfony" command don't work on fedora (symfony : command not found)

Tags: symfony

I'm working on Linux fedora and I want to use Symfony for a project.
I already installed Symfony, but when I use Symfony commands it doesn't work (command not found).
My goal is to run a server by using this command `symfony server:start`

The 2 commands I tried (sorry my shell is in French)

[image: sudo dnf install php-symfony]

*package  php-symfony-2.8.52-3 already installed*

*Dependencies solved*

*Nothing to do*

[image: symfony check:requirements]

*bash : symfony : command not found*

Comment: The `symfony` command is provided by the `symfony-cli` package, that must be just the framework (and a quite old version at that). Check official [installation method](https://symfony.com/download) for the cli.

Answer (score 1):

You have installed a very old version of the Symfony framework but, you are trying to use the Symfony CLI binary.

> Run this installer to create a binary called symfony:
>
> ```
> wget https://get.symfony.com/cli/installer -O - | bash
> ```
>
> — https://symfony.com/download

Check [the setup guide](https://symfony.com/doc/current/setup.html) for further reference.